# Can I have multiple GOPATH directories?

Tags: go

I set my GOPATH to

```
/Users/me/dev/go
```

and I have

```
/Users/me/dev/go/src/client1
/Users/me/dev/go/src/client2
/Users/me/dev/go/src/client3
```

and also

```
/Users/me/dev/client1/rails_project
/Users/me/dev/client2/php_project
etc.
```

I don't like how in my root dev folder I'm forced to have this general "go" dir that holds many different client's go projects.

Comment: Yes. Separate entries : or ; depending on OS.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Yes, `GOPATH` is a list of directories (like `PATH`). Run `go help gopath` for details. For example, on Linux, I have:

```
$ go env
GOROOT="/home/peter/go"
GOPATH="/home/peter/gopath:/home/peter/public/gopath"
$
```

I have something similar on Windows.

Note: Linux uses `:` as the `GOPATH` list separator; Windows uses `;` as the separator.

If you use `go get` it will default to the first directory in the list.

Run `go env` to check that everything is correct.

Comment: Unfortunately, this still causes all kinds of grief as tooling doesn't seem to handle multiple GOPATH well. For example, vendor directories are only picked up in the first item in the path; `go get` only works against the first item in the path; most (all?) vendor management tools don't expect to have more than one item in the path; different workpaths are considered to be in different "trees". And, packages in more than one location (vendored) get a bit screwy. I'm still trying to figure all this out, but haven't found a good solution, yet.

Comment: Great answer (and totally solved my problem with the dreaded: Error loading workspace: You are outside of a module and outside of $GOPATH/src. If you are using modules, please open your editor to a directory in your module.)  Thanks!

Answer (score 27):

[This blog post](https://dmitri.shuralyov.com/blog/18) gives a very nice explanation about how and why one would set multiple values in GOPATH, especially when it says:

> My GOPATH consists of 3 folders or GOPATH workspaces.
>
> The first one is my **landing workspace**. Since it's listed first, whenever I go get any new package, it always ends up in this workspace.
>
> Go searches each directory listed in GOPATH to find source code, but new packages are always downloaded into the first directory in the list.
>   I make it a rule to never do any development in there, so it's always completely safe to clean this folder whenever it gets too large (with Go packages I don't use). After all, it only has Go packages that I can get again with go get.
>
> My second workspace is for all **my personal Go packages** and any other packages I may want to "favorite" or do some development on. I move things I use regularly from first workspace into second.
>
> My third workspace is dedicated to **the private Go packages from my work**, and their dependencies. It's convenient to have my work packages separate from all my personal stuff, so they don't get in each other's way.

Answer (score 17):

Yes.

To cite Go itself:

```
$ go help gopath
```

> The Go path is used to resolve import statements.
>   It is implemented by and documented in the go/build package.
>
> The GOPATH environment variable lists places to look for Go code.
>   On Unix, the value is a colon-separated string.
>   On Windows, the value is a semicolon-separated string.
>   On Plan 9, the value is a list.
>
> GOPATH must be set to get, build and install packages outside the
>   standard Go tree.
>
> Each directory listed in GOPATH must have a prescribed structure:
>
> The src directory holds source code.  The path below src
>   determines the import path or executable name.
>
> ...