# Why is $GOPATH often set in ~/.bashrc and ~/.bash_profile instead of ~/.profile?

Tags: go, environment-variables, gopath

In Go's wiki page on Github, it is told to be set in ~/.bash_profile:

https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Setting-GOPATH

In this StackOverflow question most of the top voted answers suggested to be set in the ~/.bashrc file:

[how do I SET the GOPATH environment variable on Ubuntu? What file must I edit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21001387/how-do-i-set-the-gopath-environment-variable-on-ubuntu-what-file-must-i-edit)

I have read that ~/.profile is perhaps the best way to set environment variables. Is there a reason that ~/.profile is not used to set $GOPATH or is it just a matter of preference?

Comment: Answers that suggest `.bashrc` are incorrect, there's just too many people that don't know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Use your shell profile

If you have a `.bash_profile` file already, you can use it, else use `.profile`. You could also source `.profile` from `.bash_profile` and add anything you need to `.profile` instead; see [this answer for more info](https://superuser.com/a/183980/135137).

#### Why not `.bashrc`?

If you add environment variables to `.bashrc`, you can experience things like [duplicate `PATH` entries](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14895/duplicate-entries-in-path-a-problem), but it also means those vars are only available in a process launched from a shell. For `GOPATH`, that usually isn't a problem, but [it is `PATH`-like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36017724/can-i-have-multiple-gopath-directories), so you should stick with the shell profile to avoid any potential issues.