# Importing a local file

Tags: go

I'm really new to Go and I'm trying to import a local file in the main.go.
This is how the project is structured:

```
-project_name(dir)
--src(dir)
---main.go
---auth(dir)
----signup.go
```

I'm trying to use a function I wrote in `signup.go` in `main.go`.
This is how I tried to import the `signup.go` in `main.go`:

```
import (
  "encoding/json"
  "fmt"
  "log"
  "net/http"

  "github.com/gorilla/mux"
  auth "./auth"
)
```

and use it like that:

```
myRouter.HandleFunc("/signup", auth.signupUser).Methods("POST")
```

I also tried copying the relative `auth dir` and write it in the import but I still get an error `undefined: auth go`

I tried looking for answers but I can't see what I'm doing differently from the answers I saw.

Comment: Add `project_name` to `GOPATH` environment variable, perhaps these will help [Relative Imports in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38517593/relative-imports-in-go) and [Multiple Directories Gopath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36017724/can-i-have-multiple-gopath-directories)

Comment: You do not import files in go, you only import packages. Do not use relative imports for packages. Start with [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html), which explains all the details necessary to create a simple package and import it.

Comment: @GauravDhiman Please correct me if I'm wrong, but from what I understood, I need to create my project in the GOPATH. So if my go directory (and GOPATH) is at /home/go, I need to create all of my project there? Because I have a different directory for all my projects and it's not /home/go.

Comment: @JohnDoah not necessarily, you can add multiple directories in `GOPATH`, however keep your projects organized i wouldn't recommend adding different directory for each project in `GOPATH`

Comment: `auth.signupUser` is an unexported identifier so you won't be able to use it from another package. Please take the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/) to get a good overview of the language fundamentals.

Comment: Use go modules. You don't need to create your project under `GOPATH` anymore: https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules

Answer (score -1):

Relative imports are not recommended in Go.

If `project_name` is inside your GOPATH, like `$GOPATH/github.com/john/project_name`, you can import `auth` like this:

```
import "github.com/john/project_name/src/auth"
```

If you are using [Go modules](https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules), then instead of `github.com/john/project_name`, use whatever name is inside your `go.mod`. If you are not using Go modules but would like to, you can do `go mod init github.com/john/project_name` whilst inside the `project_name` folder, and then that folder will be used as a base.

Note that `signupUser` has to actually be `SignupUser` to be exported (and therefore useable).